# Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "AppName" target's entitlements

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

Automatic signing can't add the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements to your provisioning profile. Switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a matching provisioning profile from the developer website. Alternatively, to continue using automatic signing, remove these entitlements from your entitlements file and their associated functionality from your code.

> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile:
>   com.company.AppName" doesn't include the application-identifier and
>   keychain-access-groups entitlements.

In Simulator it is running fine, but using the device getting this error.
Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Running on simulator does not require any profile or certificate but running on device it does. Without proper profile you cannot run on any device. If you do not need Keychain sharing switch of the same in target->capabilities

Comment: but yesterday i run it in device and no issues...

Comment: When did you turned on keychain sharing?

Comment: i am not turned on keychain sharing,

Comment: problem is getting when adding development team